# Angular2 systemjs throws 503s

Tags: javascript, angular, gulp

I have a simple app written in Angular2 with no external calls to any resources. I have around 10 components with its own html and css in separate files. I use gulp to create the dist package and deploy to a testing environment where I have 10 concurrent requests as maximum.

If I open the site I very often get 503 two/three times (refreshing) before getting the actual page to load. The error I get is:

```
(index):23 Error: Fetch error: 503 Service Unavailable
  Instantiating http://test.site.com/vendor/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js
  Loading http://test.site.com/vendor/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js
  Loading http://test.site.com/app/main.js
  Loading app
    at /vendor/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1500:13 [<root>]
    at Zone.run (zone.js:125) [<root> => <root>]
    at /vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:760:57 [<root>]
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:165) [<root> => <root>]
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:593) [<root>]
```

and then a bunch of extra 503s when trying to load different js files. According to the hosting provider the site is quite often under max concurrent of requests however I see all the time the "loading" text therefore I'm assuming it has nothing to do with the actual hosting itself but with the setup of my site because the index.html is served. I have read in different articles that rxjs could be responsible when doing http calls but in this case I'm using it for it. Would it help if I create a single js combining all of them (as I have read elsewhere)? I wonder whether angular is trying to load all files (css, html and js) in parallel and that's the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, bundling should help if you have a threshold limit on max concurrent requests from your hosting provider.

Can you try to increase the threshold temporarily ? That maybe the easiest way to prove that theory before you spend more time on it.

If confirmed, then go ahead with bundling to a single js file or maybe one for everything in the framework (platform browser, angular, systemjs) and one specific to your app code.

Comment: Yes, I'm in the process of creating two files, one for the everything in the framework and other for the user code. I will let you know if that worked